# Android slow frame rate

Tags: android, graphics, frame-rate

Apparently this is a popular topic. Im a beginner, so my problem is probably something fairly trivial. This is a very simple game kind of like Pong. I am using this code to draw my game:

```
@Override
public void paint(float deltaTime) {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

    // draw the game elements
    if (state == GameState.Running){
        g.drawImage(Assets.back, 0, 0);
        //g.drawRect(0, 0, g.getWidth(), g.getHeight(), Color.BLACK);           
        g.saveCanvas();
        g.drawTransRect(0, 0, scene.getLine(), g.getHeight());
        g.drawImage(Assets.fore, 0, 0);
        //g.drawRect(0, 0, g.getWidth(), g.getHeight(), Color.WHITE);
        g.restoreCanvas();  


        for (Pieces p : pieces){

            if (p.getType() == true)
                g.drawImage(Assets.pos, p.getX(), p.getY());
            if (p.getType() == false){
                g.drawImage(Assets.neg, p.getX(), p.getY());

            }
        }
    }
```

If I run the code as-is, the frame rate looks to be about 15FPS? However, use drawRect  (commented out above) instead of the drawImage (background and foreground bmps as Assets), my FPS is at least 60. Im assuming this means that there is much more CPU power involved in displaying bmps vs Rects. How can I use my images and maintain a decent framerate?

Thanks.

EDIT:

My drawImage method looks like this, if it helps:

```
 public void drawImage(Image Image, int x, int y) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage)Image).bitmap, x, y, null);
}
```

Comment: What is Graphics class? Looks like every time You call drawImage it get decoded.

Comment: Ive added the draw method above. What do you mean when you say that every time drawImage is called it is "decoded."

Comment: How big are your images?  drawRect has significantly less overhead to draw beecause it's s single color.

Comment: My images are B&W. I switched to jpg: the two images are ~40kb, and the game still lags pretty hard. This file size is not too big is it? I'm not really sure what I should do to try and improve performance?

Comment: hmm, I would suggest You to try this way http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html and put startMethodTracing at the start of the method and stopMethodTracing at the end. So, You'll be see exact place where most of time spent.